# Pantone Color for Gold Metal (on furniture)

Tags: color, pantone, metal, metallic

we are working on creating a furniture piece made mostly of metal. We would like this metal to be colored gold. The manufacturer can only use Pantone colors to color the metal. We have located Pantone 871C as a likely candidate for gold (see image below)
[image: Pantone 871C sample]

However, the issue is the 871C is coming out very bland and lacks the shine of gold. Please see the second image below about comparing the Pantone 871C color sprayed on the metal square (in the middle) compared with two gold colored metal pieces (on either side). The Pantone 871C looks so dull by comparison.

[image: comparison of gold colors]

Is there any way to use Pantone to color metal shiny gold? If there is, how is this done and with which Pantone color?

Comment: At Pantone's Web there's a difference between Graphic Designers and Industrial Designers inks https://www.pantone.com/color-finder?q=871 Are you using the right one?

Comment: It's metallic paint.  Why would you expect paint to look like real shiny metal/brass/gold?  Speak to your manufacturer to resolve the issue. This isn't a graphic design question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a manufacturing issue and not a graphic design one.

Comment: It's *also* worth pointing out that the tubes you have in your picture had discrete curved surfaces and filleted corners, as well as a noticeable clearcoat - the ***flat*** *plate* sample swatch you have of your metallic 871C will not show the specular highlight and gradient one sees with the corner and curve conditions, due to its being, well... flat. Literally. And as others have said, the sample you find was not the appropriate one for your situation - I'd ask that furniture manufacturer ***which*** Pantone library ***they*** use - and find your tone match there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the color you chose, and the photo looks pretty similar. But you are looking for in the wrong catalog.

Take a look at this:

https://www.pantone.com/color-finder?q=Gold

There are a lot of options.

[image]

https://www.pantone.com/color-systems/for-product-design

871C is for coated paper, you need to look in another catalog.

I agree that the Pantone's product page is a real mess. Pure "Mumble Jumble" and not clear explanations and classifications.

You can simply contact them: https://www.pantone.com/about/contact-us

---

One option is asking the product manufacturer.

"Guys... I need a really pretty gold color, what options do you DO have".